# Calling Scope of Related Model in WhereHas Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm using Lumen 5.5 and want to create a scope that limits the query to a constraint in another model. Here's my relevant code.

Post model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user-id', 'user-id');
}
public function scopeActive()
{
    return $this->where('status', '=', '1')->whereHas('user', function($q) {
        $q->activeUser();
    });
}
```

And in the users model:

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post', 'user-id');
}
public function scopeActiveUser()
{
    return $this->whereDate('seen', '>=', date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 months')));
}
```

It seems that `activeUser()` in the `whereHas` in the Post model isn't being triggered.

Replacing `activeUser()` with `whereDate('seen', '>=', date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 months')))` works fine but misses the scoping abilities of Lumen/Laravel.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you make a scope in laravel that calls various other scopes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32695608/can-you-make-a-scope-in-laravel-that-calls-various-other-scopes)

Comment: @Maraboc pointed me in the right direction :)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `$query` part as described [in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#local-scopes):

```
public function scopeActive($query)
{
    return $query->where('status', '=', '1')->whereHas('user', function($q) {
        $q->activeUser();
    });
}
```

And:

```
public function scopeActiveUser($query)
{
    return $query->whereDate('seen', '>=', date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 months')));
}
```

Comment: Works and will accept your answer as soon as I can - in the meantime I'm trying to understand when would I use $this compared to $query?

Comment: @Michał you can use `$this` in simple methods defined in the model, for example `return $this->find(4);`, but you can't do this in local scopes.